# XCode 6.3 Automate application launch with AppleScript

Tags: ios, xcode, applescript

I'm developing an application for iOS and I'm using quite a lot of multithreading.

Because of that there are some nasty race conditions that sometimes cause a crash. It happens very rarely and in order to do produce the crash I need to manually launch my project hundreds of times.

My question is, is there a way to automate launches with Xcode 6.3 and Applescript?

I've seen scripts for XCode 4.0 and I tried writing one myself:

```
 repeat 100 times
    tell application "Xcode"
        open "<PathToProject>/TestApplication.xcodeproj"
        tell project "TestApplication"
            clean
            build
            try 
                debug
            end try
        end tell
    end tell
 end repeat
```

From what I can tell it does run the `clean` and `build` commands but it just won't execute the `debug` or `launch` keywords.